# Odd close reason for the following post

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

The following [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27966/why-are-particular-laser-related-skin-products-not-recommended-for-darker-skin-t) was closed for we don't do personal medical advice. Unless we know this person has dark skin, we can't jump to the conclusion this is a personal question, and even if we know their skin tone, this person could be curious to why laser products work differently on different skin tones.

I don't see how in good conscious we can say this is a personal medical advice question. The question was PSQ (problem statement question) with no initial research, but I edited the question to include the basic information on the devices which should allow the question to fit with the policy.

If anyone is going to use the personal medical advice close reason, I suggest they re-read the question a second time before jumping to conclusions. A personal question generally contains the pronoun I or me. Asking why something is no good for a group of people seems pretty broad.

Comment: You provided product information. It's better than nothing, but it didn't encourage the OP to do any investigation. The answer is interesting: that [darkly pigmented areas absorb more energy](http://www.livescience.com/9195-shining-light-pros-cons-laser-hair-removal.html) and burn. It's also easy to find. It boils down to whether *gimme teh codez* questions are good for the site overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree in this case - the question appeared to be asking why this might be the case from a scientific stand point and was not asking for advice, nor would the answers to this question be expected to give medical advise.  I have reopened it.

Comment: Awesome! That is great.

Comment: I did not close vote for reasons of personal medical advice. I did so because there was no research done. When you reopen a question, do all the close votes disappear?

Comment: @anongoodnurse If multiple close vote reasons are cast the reason displayed goes with the majority verdict (in this case personal medical questions).  Ordinarily it takes 5 reopen votes to reopen a question which does reset the close vote counter to 0.  Moderator votes (as in several other places) are binding and only take one rather than five.